# Is it possible to encrypt or hide the paypal auto return url?

Tags: html, paypal

I have a program that I wish to sell via paypal, but once the user pays for the software, they are taken to a download page which is simple to share. I know I can
t prevent people from sharing the file, but the customers who buy this software are not often that savvy, so making it a little difficult to share the link would probably work quite well. I thought maybe of passing a url parameter from the auto return that enabled the download? My web host is only html, so some of the more backend options won't work. I could email the link, but I was hoping for an auto response. I could password protect the file and have the password emailed, but that is less appealing. If anyone has a simple deterrent solution, I would love to hear it (hiding the url I guess is not possible with many browsers now?)

Comment: Are you using a database to keep track of the purchases..? If so, you could create an email/key pair to grant access to the software (and track downloads/usage, among other things..).

Comment: I just keep the purchase info locally. You are suggesting a reg key that I would email to the customer. Maybe they could use the software as a trial until they register? Yes, that would work. I guess I need to add some code for registration. I was thinking something along the lines of a download url page that the user can only get to if they go through the paypal payment.

Comment: I ended up doing an email key with a trial. thanks

Comment: Voted to close - my origional title is not what I asked--I know far more now. This was easily solved my generating code keys in a DB and mailing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**test_dl_test.php::**

```
<?php
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$key = $_REQUEST['key'];
$go = $_REQUEST['go'];

/*
$query = "SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE key LIKE '".$key."' AND email LIKE '".$email."'"; // instead of (*), you could get the URL
$result = mysqli_query($db_handler,$query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($dh_handler));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!=1) {
    die("ERROR! Purchase history not found!");
}
// OPTIONALLY
// $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// $software_url = result['URL'];

*/

if ($go==1) {   
    $url = "http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/vbMedia/Audio/Lossless_WAV_Compression/Sample_APE_File.zip";
    header('Location: '.$url);
}

?>

<html>
<a href="test_dl_test.php?go=1&email=someone@somehwere.com&key=12340589knd9af8i">click here!</a>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, and I am sure it would work, but my web host is only HTML. I think it is a bit beyond my capability (does paypal post info like email, etc, to the return url--by default?) Thanks though